# Local tests with AWS Cloud Development Kit (CDK)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I recently started to develop a serverless application using the AWS CDK with typescript. It's a much better option than doing everything via console since I can host the code in a repository and the organization and maintenance also benefit greatly from this feature. However one of the points that the aws console helped a lot was the quick tests that could be done, you wrote a lambda and could test it right there without problems. However, with the CDK, you need to deploy first, throw the updates in the cloud and only then be able to test there. Is there any way to test the CDK locally? Not just lambdas, but something that simulates aws features as a whole?

Answer (score 1):

The testing process for the AWS CDK is described in the ***AWS Cloud Development Kit (CDK)
Developer Guide***. This topic contains a lot of detailed information. However, there is no mention of how to test locally. See this topic for more information.

[Testing constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/testing.html)

Comment: This is a correct answer and I would add that in order to test some components locally e.g. Lambda, you can take a look at AWS Serverless Application Model (SAM). If there is a question what to use, I would stick to AWS CDK, though, if you are interested in serverless - check AWS SAM. They both use CloudFormation underneath, but functionality is a bit different. Let's take Lambda for instance: (1) both can build a function, (2) AWS CDK provides a convenient python interface, (3) AWS SAM allows you test it locally. In my opinion, both can be used simultaneously to get each's advantage.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely write unit tests to run locally before deploying. However, it sounds like you're looking for a way to test the entire service. That is more complicated and unsolved. A good starting point might be to look at the new SAM-CDK tooling
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/better-together-aws-sam-and-aws-cdk/